Barman using old pg_start_backup on Postgresql-15
I'm trying to backup my server using barman but it's taking error on backup
here's the check
    root@barman:~# barman check My_server
Server Postgres_UniContent:
        PostgreSQL: OK
        superuser or standard user with backup privileges: OK
        PostgreSQL streaming: OK
        wal_level: OK
        replication slot: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        backup minimum size: OK (0 B)
        wal maximum age: OK (no last_wal_maximum_age provided)
        wal size: OK (0 B)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 0 backups, expected at least 0)
        ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
        systemid coherence: OK
        pg_receivexlog: OK
        pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
        receive-wal running: OK
        archive_mode: OK
        archive_command: OK
        continuous archiving: OK
        archiver errors: OK

you guys see everything is okay but then when I start backup
root@barman:~# barman backup My_server
Starting backup using rsync-concurrent method for server My_server in /barman/My_server/base/20241002T184311
ERROR: Backup failed issuing start backup command.
DETAILS: pg_start_backup command: function pg_start_backup(unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: ...heckpoint()) AS timeline, now() AS timestamp FROM pg_start_b...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

So, as I see it's using pg_start_backup(unknown, boolean, boolean) but in Postgresql-15 the function name changed into pg_backup_start(). But I already grant the function to barman user
 grantee | function_schema |      routine_name       | privilege_type 
---------+-----------------+-------------------------+----------------
 barman  | postgres        | pg_backup_start         | EXECUTE
 barman  | postgres        | pg_backup_stop          | EXECUTE
 barman  | postgres        | pg_create_restore_point | EXECUTE
 barman  | postgres        | pg_switch_wal           | EXECUTE
(4 rows)

postgres=# GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_backup_start(text, boolean) to barman;
GRANT
postgres=# GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_backup_stop(boolean) to barman;
GRANT
postgres=# GRANT pg_checkpoint TO barman;
GRANT ROLE

here is the diagnose information
root@barman:/barman# barman diagnose
{
    "global": {
        "config": {
            "barman_home": "/barman",
            "barman_user": "barman",
            "configuration_files_directory": "/etc/barman.d",
            "errors_list": [],
            "log_file": "/barman/barman.log",
            "log_level": "DEBUG"
        },
        "system_info": {
            "barman_ver": "2.18",
            "kernel_ver": "Linux barman 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux",
            "python_ver": "",
            "release": "Distributor ID:\tUbuntu\nDescription:\tUbuntu 22.04.5 LTS\nRelease:\t22.04\nCodename:\tjammy",
            "rsync_ver": "rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31",
            "ssh_ver": "",
            "timestamp": "Wed Oct  2 19:19:08 2024"
        }
    },
    "servers": {
        "My_server": {
            "backups": {
                "20241002T184311": {
                    "backup_id": "20241002T184311",
                    "backup_label": null,
                    "begin_offset": null,
                    "begin_time": null,
                    "begin_wal": null,
                    "begin_xlog": null,
                    "config_file": "/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf",
                    "copy_stats": null,
                    "deduplicated_size": null,
                    "end_offset": null,
                    "end_time": null,
                    "end_wal": null,
                    "end_xlog": null,
                    "error": "failure issuing start backup command (pg_start_backup command: function pg_start_backup(unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist)",
                    "hba_file": "/etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_hba.conf",
                    "ident_file": "/etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_ident.conf",
                    "included_files": null,
                    "mode": "rsync-concurrent",
                    "pgdata": "/pg_data/main",
                    "server_name": "My_server",
                    "size": null,
                    "status": "FAILED",
                    "systemid": "7412892106944724954",
                    "tablespaces": null,
                    "timeline": null,
                    "version": 150008,
                    "xlog_segment_size": 16777216
                }
            },
            "config": {
                "active": true,
                "archiver": true,
                "archiver_batch_size": 0,
                "backup_directory": "/barman/My_server",
                "backup_method": "rsync",
                "backup_options": "concurrent_backup",
                "bandwidth_limit": null,
                "barman_home": "/barman",
                "barman_lock_directory": "/barman",
                "basebackup_retry_sleep": 30,
                "basebackup_retry_times": 0,
                "basebackups_directory": "/barman/My_server/base",
                "check_timeout": 30,
                "compression": null,
                "conninfo": "host=IP_ADDRESS user=barman dbname=postgres",
                "create_slot": "auto",
                "custom_compression_filter": null,
                "custom_compression_magic": null,
                "custom_decompression_filter": null,
                "description": "Univision content watch information collecting server",
                "disabled": false,
                "errors_directory": "/barman/My_server/errors",
                "forward_config_path": false,
                "immediate_checkpoint": false,
                "incoming_wals_directory": "/barman/My_server/incoming",
                "last_backup_maximum_age": null,
                "last_backup_minimum_size": null,
                "last_wal_maximum_age": null,
                "max_incoming_wals_queue": null,
                "minimum_redundancy": 0,
                "msg_list": [],
                "name": "My_server",
                "network_compression": false,
                "parallel_jobs": 2,
                "path_prefix": "/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin",
                "post_archive_retry_script": null,
                "post_archive_script": null,
                "post_backup_retry_script": null,
                "post_backup_script": null,
                "post_delete_retry_script": null,
                "post_delete_script": null,
                "post_recovery_retry_script": null,
                "post_recovery_script": null,
                "post_wal_delete_retry_script": null,
                "post_wal_delete_script": null,
                "pre_archive_retry_script": null,
                "pre_archive_script": null,
                "pre_backup_retry_script": null,
                "pre_backup_script": null,
                "pre_delete_retry_script": null,
                "pre_delete_script": null,
                "pre_recovery_retry_script": null,
                "pre_recovery_script": null,
                "pre_wal_delete_retry_script": null,
                "pre_wal_delete_script": null,
                "primary_ssh_command": null,
                "recovery_options": "",
                "retention_policy": "window 30 d",
                "retention_policy_mode": "auto",
                "reuse_backup": null,
                "slot_name": "on",
                "ssh_command": "ssh postgres@IP_ADDRESS",
                "streaming_archiver": true,
                "streaming_archiver_batch_size": 0,
                "streaming_archiver_name": "barman_receive_wal",
                "streaming_backup_name": "barman_streaming_backup",
                "streaming_conninfo": "host=IP_ADDRESS user=streaming_barman dbname=postgres",
                "streaming_wals_directory": "/barman/My_server/streaming",
                "tablespace_bandwidth_limit": null,
                "wal_retention_policy": "simple-wal 30 d",
                "wals_directory": "/barman/My_server/wals"
            },
            "status": {
                "archive_command": "rsync -a %p barman@BARMAN_IPADD:/barman/My_server/incoming/%f",
                "archive_mode": "on",
                "archive_timeout": 0,
                "archived_count": 6,
                "checkpoint_timeout": 300,
                "config_file": "/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf",
                "connection_error": null,
                "current_archived_wals_per_second": 3.2541333136528836e-06,
                "current_lsn": "A/CD000148",
                "current_size": 34695948524.0,
                "current_xlog": "000000010000000A000000CD",
                "data_checksums": "off",
                "data_directory": "/pg_data/main",
                "failed_count": 0,
                "has_backup_privileges": true,
                "hba_file": "/etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_hba.conf",
                "hot_standby": "on",
                "ident_file": "/etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_ident.conf",
                "is_archiving": true,
                "is_in_recovery": false,
                "is_superuser": true,
                "last_archived_time": "Wed Oct  2 18:41:58 2024",
                "last_archived_wal": "000000010000000A000000CC",
                "last_failed_time": null,
                "last_failed_wal": null,
                "max_replication_slots": "4",
                "max_wal_senders": "4",
                "pg_receivexlog_compatible": true,
                "pg_receivexlog_installed": true,
                "pg_receivexlog_path": "/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/pg_receivewal",
                "pg_receivexlog_supports_slots": true,
                "pg_receivexlog_synchronous": false,
                "pg_receivexlog_version": "15.8",
                "pgespresso_installed": false,
                "postgres_systemid": "7412892106944724954",
                "replication_slot": [
                    "on",
                    true,
                    "A/CD000000"
                ],
                "replication_slot_support": true,
                "server_txt_version": "15.8",
                "stats_reset": "Wed Sep 11 11:09:01 2024",
                "streaming": true,
                "streaming_supported": true,
                "streaming_systemid": "7412892106944724954",
                "synchronous_standby_names": [
                    ""
                ],
                "timeline": 1,
                "wal_compression": "off",
                "wal_keep_size": "0",
                "wal_level": "replica",
                "xlog_segment_size": 16777216,
                "xlogpos": "A/CD000148"
            },
            "system_info": {
                "kernel_ver": "Linux unicontent 5.15.0-119-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 2 19:25:20 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux",
                "python_ver": "",
                "release": "Distributor ID:\tUbuntu\nDescription:\tUbuntu 22.04.2 LTS\nRelease:\t22.04\nCodename:\tjammy",
                "rsync_ver": "rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31",
                "ssh_ver": ""
            },
            "wals": {
                "last_archived_wal_per_timeline": {}
            }
        }
    }
}

Please help me to troubleshoot this barman difficulties.

Well, upgrade barman.

I've just realized that the barman server version is 2.11, after updating it to 3.11, the problem was solved.
